# Router in client mode - Remote access?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have router A which is my internet wireless distributor.

Now I have router B which I've connected to a TV so to stream content to it.

B is configured as Client of A.

No matter what I cannot access B's configuration when I am connected to router A only (I mean, no ethernet cable directly to B).

I've set B ip as 192.168.10.2

A is 192.168.10.1

No response from .2

First of all I would like to know if is it at least possible in this configuration or if a router configured as client (wifi) cannot be accessed thru the wireless interface.

If possible, I would like to know how to proper configure B, bridge or gateway, dhcp active or not, etc.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found out what was wrong. I had AP Isolation active... man this thing drove me nuts...